# Tidyverse: using pivot_wide when data are dependent on multiple columns

Tags: r, pivot, tidyverse

I searched similar questions but couldn't find an answer to what I am trying to achieve. I have a dataset that is set up like so:

```
ID    Trial   Treatment   Frequency  Value   
A       1      Control    8000       65.1   
A       1      Top        8000       62.8    
A       1      Bottom     8000       60.3  
A       1      Control    9000       63.1   
A       1      Top        9000       66.2    
A       1      Bottom     9000       69.8
A       2      Control    8000       67.6   
A       2      Top        8000       63.4    
A       2      Bottom     8000       71.9 
A       2      Control    9000       59.7  
A       2      Top        9000       63.3  
A       2      Bottom     9000       57.2
```

Each `ID` (altogether there are 27) is subjected to three `Treatment` of playbacks of sounds at either 8000 or 9000 Hz (`Frequency`). The process is repeated twice, meaning there are multiple `Trial`.

I want to use `pivot_wider` on the `Treatment` column to end up with a table that looks like:

```
ID   Trial   Frequency   Control   Top   Bottom   
A    1       8000        65.1      62.8  60.3
A    2       8000        67.6      63.4  71.9  
A    1       9000        63.1      66.2  69.8
A    2       9000        59.7      63.3  57.2
```

Reproducible data:

```
df <- read.table(text="ID  Trial  Treatment   Frequency  Value   
A       1      Control    8000  65.1   
A       1      Top    8000  62.8    
A       1      Bottom   8000  60.3  
A       1      Control    9000  63.1   
A       1      Top    9000  66.2    
A       1      Bottom  9000  69.8 
A       2      Control  8000  67.6  
A       2      Top      8000  63.4  
A       2      Bottom   8000   71.9 
A       2      Control    9000  59.7  
A       2      Top      9000  63.3  
A       2      Bottom     9000  57.2", strin=F,h=T)
```

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = Treatment, values_from = Value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could create an index column with `rowid` (if there duplicate elements for ID, Treatment) and then do the reshaping to wide format with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
    mutate(rid = rowid(ID, Treatment))  %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = Treatment, values_from = c(Value))
# A tibble: 4 x 6
#  ID    Trial Frequency Control   Top Bottom
#  <chr> <int>     <int>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 A         1      8000    65.1  62.8   60.3
#2 A         1      9000    63.1  66.2   69.8
#3 A         2      8000    67.6  63.4   71.9
#4 A         2      9000    59.7  63.3   57.2
```

---

Or another option is to apply a function i.e. `mean` for the 'Value' column so that we get the average value for any duplicates

```
df %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = Treatment, values_from = c(Value), values_fn = mean)
```

Comment: Thanks. This works on the data I have shared here, but when I tried previously on my full dataset the values spread across multiple rows.

Comment: @r_noob Is it based on the example you showed

Comment: @r_noob what is the output you are getting

Comment: I end up with something like

A    1   8000   65.1   NA   NA
A    1   8000   NA    62.8   NA
A    1   8000   NA     NA   60.3

Sorry, if that isn't helpful..

Comment: @r_noob is it based on the same example

Comment: no, the example works fine. The issue is when I try implement it to my larger dataset.

Comment: @r_noob in that case, the dataset may have duplicates.  can you try the updated post